# How does NAT keep track of connections

Tags: nat

Given a NAT where multiple PCs are sharing one IP address, how is NAT able to know where to send the incoming data to. Does it translate th SYN-ACK ids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a device connects to a server on the other side of the router, it uses a source port in its ephemeral port range. This is typically a port between 49152 and 65535 and it is randomly assigned. The NAT router records this port number as well as the destination IP address in a NAT translation table. When data starts coming back in from the server, it looks up where it goes from this table.

Comment: So it translates the source **port**.. and later looks up the translation to get back to the correct private IP and source port. Is this correct?

Comment: It translates the IP address. Some devices might translate the source port as well. The important thing to note is that it has a table of these source ports that it uses to reverse translation on return packets.

Answer (score 0):

> Given a NAT where multiple PCs are
>   sharing one IP address, how is NAT
>   able to know where to send the
>   incoming data.

By not being programmed with alheimer as model. Basically it has a memory - about which internal ports / ip addresses map to whiche external target port / ip, so it can do the translation. For TCP that is simple, for UDP the internal program better regularly sends packets outside (so that NAT refreshes the routing table).

> Does it translate th SYN-ACK ids?

No, proper NAT is not following the TCP protocol. THis is to make sure that TCP does not work.

Joke aside - NATURALLY it has to do translations when needed, otherwise it would break the implementation. NAT has to be trnasparent, so it has to make all translations necessary.